# How to use a 16x1 Multiplexer?

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer

I have 16 PIR sensors that I’m using for a project on a Raspberry Pi. The output of the PIR sensors is connected to the 16 inputs of the multiplexer. However I don’t know what to hook up to the select input(s) to read the readings from the PIR sensors that is/are currently being tripped. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would say you need to connect some output pins of the RPI.

Comment: Well, you need to read the multiplexer's datasheet.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you provide the part number of the multiplexer you are using.

However, a 16 input mux must have four digital "Select" or "Address" inputs - the bit pattern you apply to these inputs will select which one of the data inputs is fed to the data output.

The mux may also have one or more Enable pins which must be set correctly for the mux to function.

The datasheet for the part you are using should contain the necessary information to use the part correctly.

Comment: Just want to say that while you do need 4 inputs for your normal 16:1 MUX, some MUXes are SPI enabled and as such might have 4 pins but these aren't for selection directly, these are to connect to the SPI pins of the RPi (MOSI,MISO,SCK,CS) and communication has to be correctly configured for this. In other words an SPI Mux needs 4 pins despite if its a 2:1 mux or a 256:1 mux - its all in the communication protocol. In the same way, an I2C one will have 2 pins. OP might have gotten one of these so I just wanted to comment this to reduce any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any particular part, so I am going to use the ADG406 16:1 multiplexer as an example, [datasheet available here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG406_407_426.pdf)

Looking at the datasheet, the input is selected with 5 pins: EN, A0, A1, A2, A3.

[image: ADG406 control pins]

To select an input, simply drive the correct combination of control pins HIGH; e.g. to select input 10, drive EN, A0, and A3 high

[image: ADG406 truth table]

Comment: Some multiplexers also have a latch the address, otherwise it will ignore the address on the inputs and just keep using the old address. Such as the ADG732